# How to detect running on a real device?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

I am working on a universal application, and I am trying to detect whether it runs on a desktop computer or on a real IoT device (Raspberry PI 2). Following the recommendation, I am trying to use API contract checks, however this returns `true` even on the desktop machine:

```
ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent( "Windows.Devices.DevicesLowLevelContract", 1, 0 );
```

Obviously when I try to call `GpioController.GetDefault()`, it fails on the desktop, but strangely with a `FileNotFoundException`: `"The specified module could not be found."`

So what is the right way to detect a real device?

Thanks for your help,

György

**Edit:**

On some desktops `GpioController.GetDefault()` returns `null`, while on other machines it fails with `FileNotFoundException`.

**Edit:**

My goal is to ensure that I can safely call any GPIO or IoT Core specific APIs without using try-catch blocks everywhere to handle exceptions when running on a non-IoT device.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the type of device your app is running on by

```
Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily
```

Source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.analyticsversioninfo.aspx

Microsoft does suggest to maximise your reach with universal apps by checking for capabilities instead of just checking the device family.
There's an article about all that here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tom. The `AnalyticsInfo` class you mentioned is for "profiling purposes" (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.analyticsinfo), which means to me that it is there for logging and diagnostics. Yes, I agree, Microsoft recommends using API contracts (see https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/15/dynamically-detecting-features-with-api-contracts-10-by-10/) to detect features, that's exactly why I try to use them, however it returns wrong data.

Comment: Check out the answer from Daniel Meixner on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479171/windows-10-uap-determine-if-device-is-iot-e-g-raspberry-pi-2 He suggest checking if the GpioController type is present, I haven't tried it out myself yet.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but unfortunately IsTypePresent for the GpioController class also returns true on the desktop :(

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what aspect of a "real device" you want to check. Using API Contract information is not a good proxy, as you have found (although it should return `null`, not crash, on desktop -- that's a bug). Using `AnalyticsInfo` can be a reasonable proxy but you have to be careful about receiving new values over time, plus it actually identifies the OS type rather than the physical hardware. Enumerating hardware devices is the best way to detect hardware, but they can come and go dynamically as the user plugs and unplugs them.

What is it you are looking to do differently based on the answer?

Comment: I just want to decide, whether I can use the GpioController and GpioPin classes or they will fail, because there is no GPIO available on the current hardware. So I don't really care about the OS type or the device family, what I want to know is whether the API is available. I was under the impression that it is the purpose of API contracts. Thanks for your answer, Peter.

Comment: I can confirm, that on some desktops `GpioController.GetDefault()` returns `null`, while on other machines it fails with `FileNotFoundException`. Strange.

Comment: Peter, the MSDN page of the `AnalyticsInfo` class states, that it exists "for profiling purposes", and a blog post (https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/15/dynamically-detecting-features-with-api-contracts-10-by-10/) from the Windows 10 team recommends using API contracts to detect features. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: The primary purpose of the API is for analytics, but there are occasions where it can be useful... But there is usually a better mechanism (hence the question about what your ultimate goal was). API Contracts are for detecting if an API is available on a device, but it doesn't tell you anything about hardware (eg the camera APIs are always available but most PCs don't have webcams... but then a user could add one at any minute via USB). What build number has the exception vs. returning Null?

Comment: I tried the code on 10240 and on 10586, and if I remember correctly, it was 10240 that throw the exception, and 10586 returned null.

Comment: Good, sounds like the bug was fixed.